# Plotting issue when using Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, warning-messages

Please refer to the below code, not sure why the plotting gives an error (`Manipulate::vsform`).
The plotting seems to work if I remove the manipulate function.
Can someone please assist?

```
Manipulate[
 (*k = 266*1000;
 m = 3755;
 L = 2;
 r= 0.5;*)
 A = L^2/4 + L*x[t] + x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 - 0.5*L^2*Cos[theta[t]] - 
   L*x[t]*Cos[theta[t]] + 0.25*L^2*Cos[theta[t]]^2 - 
   L*y[t]*Sin[theta[t]] + 0.25*L^2*Sin[theta[t]]^2;
 B = L^2/4 - L*x[t] + x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 - 0.5*L^2*Cos[theta[t]]^2 + 
   L*x[t]*Cos[theta[t]] + 0.25*L^2*Cos[theta[t]]^2 + 
   L*y[t]*Sin[theta[t]] + 0.25*L^2*Sin[theta[t]]^2;
 oneA = 0.5*k*L^2*Sin[theta[t]] + 
   0.25*k*L^2*(-2*Cos[theta[t]]*Sin[theta[t]]) + 
   0.25*k*L*(2*Sin[theta[t]]*Cos[theta[t]]);
 oneB = -k*
   r*(0.5*L^2*Sin[theta[t]] + L*x[t]*Sin[theta[t]] + 
      0.25*L^2*(-2*Cos[theta[t]]*Sin[theta[t]]) - 
      L*y[t]*Cos[theta[t]] + 
      0.25*L^2*(2*Sin[theta[t]]*Cos[theta[t]]))/(2*Sqrt[A]);
 oneC = -k*
   r*(0.5*L^2*Sin[theta[t]] - L*x[t]*Sin[theta[t]] + 
      0.25*L^2*(2*Cos[theta[t]]*Sin[theta[t]]) + 
      L*y[t]*Cos[theta[t]] + 
      0.25*L^2*(2*Sin[theta[t]]*Cos[theta[t]]))/(2*Sqrt[B]);
 ONE = oneA + oneB + oneC;
 two = 2*k*x[t] - k*r*(L + 2*x[t] - L*Cos[theta[t]])/(2*Sqrt[A]) - 
   k*r*(-L + 2*x[t] + L*Cos[theta[t]])/(2*Sqrt[B]);
 three = -9.81*m + 2*k*y[t] - 
   k*r*(2*y[t] - L*Sin[theta[t]])/(2*Sqrt[A]) - 
   k*r*(2*y[t] + L*Sin[theta[t]])/(2*Sqrt[B]);
 S = NDSolve[{x''[t] == -two/(m), y''[t] == -three/(m), 
    theta''[t] == -ONE*4/(m*L^2), x[0] == 0.0522, y[0] == 0.6, 
    theta[0] == 0.0349, x'[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, theta'[0] == 0}, {x, 
    y, theta}, {t, 0, 20}], 
 Plot[x[t] /. S, {t, 0, 20}], {k, 50, 266*1000}, {m, 50, 3755}, {L, 
  50, 10}, {r, 0.1, 1}]
```

Comment: Try replacing the comma before `Plot` with a semicolon. Note the error message indicates that `Manipulate` thinks `Plot` is a *variable* declaration, not part of the body to be displayed.

Comment: Tangential tip: You should localize your scratch variables you use (use `Module[]` for instance. By not doing it, you're creating dependencies that tend to lead to misbehaviors if you do a lot of work and revising of the code, or have more than one thing going on in a session.